# How to find the magnitude of electric and magnetic fields in an arbitary inertial frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-electrodynamics, inertial-frames

In the context of special relativity, and using proper Lorentz transformations:

If the electromagnetic fields have an uniform value [= constant in space and time] in an inertial frame, how will the magnitude of these fields change in a different (arbitrary) inertial frame?

For example, an inertial frame which makes an angle $\alpha$, or moves with a different velocity $v'$ with respect to the original one.

Comment: There was some useful information in the comments here, but the discussion was getting rather long, so I've deleted them. I'll just leave here the link to the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help), and also mention that [meta] or [chat] are the places to ask for clarification on how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

All the necessary detail can be found in the first few paragraphs of [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity) concerning the transformations of the E- and B-fields.

As you probably know, the E- and B-fields are not invariant quantities in different uniformly moving frames of reference.

The relevant transformations, where ${\bf v}$ is a velocity (vector) of a "primed" frame with respect to the stationary "lab frame" and $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor at speed $v$, are

$$ \mathbf {{E}}' = \mathbf{{E}_{\parallel}} + \gamma \left( \mathbf {E}_{\bot} + \mathbf{ v} \times \mathbf {B} \right) $$
$$\mathbf {{B}}' = \mathbf{{B}_{\parallel}} +  \gamma \left( \mathbf {B}_{\bot} -\frac{1}{c^2} \mathbf{ v} \times \mathbf {E} \right), $$
where the parallel and perpendicular subscripts refer to components of the E- and B-field that are either parallel or perpendicular to ${\bf v}$. 
 i.e. The components parallel to ${\bf v}$ end up unchanged but the perpendicular components are transformed.